# How to execute a function after some time

Tags: javascript

I want to write a javascript code where I can execute a function after exactly 30 minutes.

say I have a function called `getScore` and another function called `getResult`. I want those functions to be executed after exactly thirty minutes.

It's for a quiz purpose, the quiz duration is thirty minutes, so after the time passes, both functions should be executed.

Comment: `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` could be methods you should look into! :)

Comment: Is the user about to stay and not reload the page during all 30-minutes period?

Comment: After 30 minutes after what ? (page load, click ona  button ?)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    getScore(); 
    getResult(); 
}, 1800000);
```

The '1800000' is the time in milliseconds after which you want this function to execute. In this case, 30 minutes.

Comment: I've replaced the w3schools ref to mdn; not many peeps like w3schools around here :)

Comment: I don't know why it's not working. setTimeout(function() {
    getScore(this.form); 
    getQs();
 showReports();
 
}, 10000);       - Im working on IE 8, is it compatible?

Comment: I suspect this.form isn't helping. `var ctx = this;` and then `getScore(ctx.form)` wherever you are trying to use this.form, perhaps?

Comment: for the other functions it's working like a charm (THANK YOU SO MUCH) except for getScore(form) its not working, any other ideas?

Comment: NP. Perhaps modify your getScore function to not require that you pass 'form', and find it again from the DOM when it is called?

Answer (score -2):

If You Want To Show Element ,you can use This Code , This Will Show Button.

```
     function myFunc(){
        var linkEd = document.getElementById("buttonID");
        var timing = 6;
        var text_timing = document.createElement("span");
        linkEd.parentNode.replaceChild(text_timing, linkEd);
        var id;
        id = setInterval(function() {timing--;
      if (timing < 0) {
        clearInterval(id);
       text_timing.parentNode.replaceChild(linkEd, text_timing);
      } else {
       text_timing.innerHTML = "<h3 class='yourclass'>Button will appear after  <strong>" + timing.toString() + "</strong>  second</h3>";
      linkEd.style.display = "inline";
      }
    }, 1000);
}
```

> This Is To Showing Time miliseconds
>
> *<h3 class='yourclass'>Button will appear after  <strong>" + timing.toString() + "
>   </strong>  second</h3>*

> To Call Time And show Button Use onclick event to show button after
>   time 0
>
> **<button class='yourclass' onclick='myFunc()' id='button'>show time</button>**
>
> use *display none* to hide the button
>
> **<button style='display:none' id='buttonID' class='yourclass'>after time</button>**

Comment: That does not specifically answer the question and is in my opinion over-complicated.